# Is my evaluation for the cumulative distribution function (CDF) right?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I want to evaluate the CDF of $X+Y-\ln(Y)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables that can only have non-negative values. To find $P(X+Y-\ln(Y)<\tau)$ I have $$P(X+Y-\ln(Y)<\tau)=\int_{l_1}^{l_2}F_X(\tau-y+\ln(y))f_Y(y)dy~~~~\text{Eq. }1$$ where $F_X(x)$ is the CDF of $X$, $f_Y(y)$ is the density function of $Y$ and $l_1$ and $l_2$ are two roots of the function $\tau-y+\ln(y)$ with $l_1 \leq l_2$. Eq. 1 can also be written as $$P(X+Y-\ln(Y)<\tau)=\int_{l_1}^{l_2}\int_0^{\tau-y+\ln(y)}f_X(x)f_Y(y)dxdy$$ Now using $y=v$ and $u=x+v$ we can write $$P(X+Y-\ln(Y)<\tau)=\int_{l_1}^{l_2}\int_v^{\tau+\ln(v)}f_X(u-v)f_Y(v)dudv.~~~~~~\text{Eq. }2$$ Is my Eq. 2 right? Or should it be $$P(X+Y-\ln(Y)<\tau)=\int_{l_1}^{l_2}\int_{e^{u-\tau}}^{u}f_X(u-v)f_Y(v)dvdu. ~~~~\text{Eq. }3$$ I obtained Eq. 3 from a research paper. I do not know how Eq. 3 is correct. Please explain why equation 3 is correct. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are a number of mistakes. First, you have not stated that $f_X$ and $f_Y$ exist. Secondly, it is $\ln y$ everywhere and not $-\ln y$. Thridly the integral w.r..t $y$ is not from $l_1$ to $l_2$ but from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thank you for your comment. Actually they both exist. Can you be a little more specific about being everywhere (because I even have $\ln(Y)$ in $P(X+Y-\ln(Y)<\tau)$ so I do not know which ones are you talking about). Thirdly, I completely agree with you about the limits of $y$ but those limits will convert to $l_1\to l_2$ because the $X$ can only take non-negative values. What do you say? And do you think Eq. 3 is right or not?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Ok I corrected the minus part. Now I do not understand why the limits will not be from $l_1$ to $l_2$. You are right that we should consider the range of values of $y$ but you can see that if we put $y=0$ then $F_X(\tau-y+\ln(y))=F_X(-\infty)=0$ so only positive values of $y$ should be considered but if we put $y$ too high then again $$F_X(\tau-y+\ln(y))=F_X(- some~postive~ value)=0$$ due to which we have to restrict $y$ to a certain range. Now equation 2 is right or still it is wrong?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy is it not like if we want to evaluate $P(X+Y<z)$ (for random  variables $X$ and $Y$ which can only take non-negative values) then we will have $$P(X+Y<z)=\int_0^{z}F_X(z-y)f_Y(y)dy$$ what do you say?In this case we can see that the limits of $Y$ are restricted from being $0\to \infty$ to $0\to z$ and that is just because of non-negativity of $X$. Is my understanding wrong

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thank you for your comment. We know that $\tau-y-\ln(y)=-\infty$ if $y=0$ and it is again $-\infty$ if we put $y=\infty$. Further the function is $\tau-y-\ln(y)$ concave and its maximum value is $\tau-1$. Now if $\tau>1$ and sufficiently high then we have a certain range of $y$ over which $\tau-y-\ln(y)>0$ and other than that range it will be negative. Therefore this range is bounded by two points which I denote by $l_1$ and $l_2$. Is it wrong reasoning?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy is there something very critical that I am missing here?